# How to test if an instance has a subclass with ForeignKey pointing to it in Django?

Tags: django

I'm new with Django and I woul like to know if the instance of `Market` I'm working on has a t least on object of class `Candle` pointing to it. As you can see in my code the relation between `Market` and `Candle` has `null=True` so it's optional.

How can I perform this check?

**models.py:**

```
class Market(models.Model):
    pair = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pair)

class Candle(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='market',
                               null= True
                               )
    dt = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

I tried many things but everytime it throw an error.

```
if instance.Candle().exists():
    ...
if Candle(market=instance).exists():
    ...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [`related_nam=market`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) you can use `market` atribute of `Market` instance to access related candles:

```
instance.market.exists() // instance - market instance
```

Or using Candle model:

```
Candle.objects.filter(market=instance).exists()
```

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed that `if Candle(market=instance):` seems to work well.

Comment: @Florent this will give you wring result. It's not even calling DB actually and I suppose always returns True. Instead you should use `Candle.objects.filter(market=instance).exists()` queryset. Check updated answer.